# How to resolve the domain name I created on domain.com in alibaba cloud SAS?

Tags: domain-name, alibaba-cloud

I have created a SAS in Alibaba cloud with ghost template as the image for SAS. I have also created a domain name on domain.com and now I am trying to configure the domain name to the ghost app running on SAS. But when I add the domain name the Resolution Status for this domain still shows as Unresolved. The below error message is displayed on the top of the console.

> Domain name, which uses Alibaba Cloud DNS, can be resolved here directly. Other domain should be resolved manually with corresponding DNS service provider.

I have also added the domain name on Alibaba Cloud DNS so I am not sure why this is still not getting resolved. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use zone.vision to check if the domain name is mapped properly?

Comment: I am not seeing a programming related question here.

Answer (score 0):

Contact your registrar to establish an A record that maps your domain name to the IP address of Alibaba Cloud SAS (Simple Application Server).

Refer:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/59080.htm